# ssmtp with gmail

Tags: centos, ssmtp, gmail

So, this is weird. Two computers, one with CentOS and one with Manjaro. Both have ssmtp, both with the same setup. Manjaro ssmtp will connect and send emails, CentOS will not:

`/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
root=email@gmail.com
hostname=manjaro-computer
AuthUser=email@gmail.com
AuthPass=PASSWORD
AuthMethod=LOGIN
FromLineOverride=yes
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=yes
UseTLS=yes
```

`/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`:

```
root:email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

The only difference is that the CentOS version has `TLS_CA_FILE` set. Without it `ssmtp` seems to hang then give up, with it enabled. I can connect to gmail but I get:

```
[<-] 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t64sm2533861itd.0 - gsmtp
ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t64sm2533861itd.0 - gsmtp)
```

Both computers are on the same network, my third server, which is FreeNAS using ssmtp I believe can also send emails no issue.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP ... >ssmtp is unmaintained. Consider using something like msmtp instead.  ....  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp

Comment: Ok, I switched to msmtp on CentOS and it works. Should I be worried about still using SSMTP on Manjaro or switch over? Since it already works there.

Comment: > Should I be worried about still using SSMTP on Manjaro or switch over? .. umaintained means possible security issues.  I would switch over to msmtp in order to ensure security updates.

Comment: As in, are there any security issues with SSMTP or can I stick with it as it still works on my other system?

Comment: One may never know if a security vulnerability in an unmaintained software packages has traversed into the realm of **exploit** ... So, I generally --being quite paranoid-- stick with maintained code backing as many packages as I can track on my Internet facing configurations..... I'm glad that the `msmtp` package seems to have fixed your immediate problem.  Perhaps, package manager software should be built to alert a user of the upstream activity state of a given package.